# General term for the polite part in an imperative sentence

Tags: grammar

Taking a few variations of an imperative sentence "Tidy your room":

```
Please tidy your room
Kindly tidy your room
Tidy your room please
```

Is there a generic term for the "Please" and "Kindly" part of the sentence i.e. a piece that doesn't change the meaning of the sentence but does alter its tone?

Also curious as to if the same term would apply to the interrogative form ("Would you tidy your room?" Vs. "Please would you tidy your room?").

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Part of speech for “please” followed by a verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46390/part-of-speech-for-please-followed-by-a-verb).