# Please put the cup there. Is "Please" an adverb in this sentence

Tags: grammar, adverbs

As per my understanding ***there*** is adverb in above sentence, but my English teacher is saying Please is the adverb in this sentence. If ***Please*** is the actual adverb in the sentence then what ***there*** will be?

Comment: Yes, ***please*** is an "adverb" in such contexts, [according to the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/264341?rskey=d2fHqB&result=3#eid). But so is ***there*** (which they specifically say is a *demonstrative adverb*).

Comment: It is a performative utterance, in fact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46390/part-of-speech-for-please-followed-by-a-verb). The short answer is "it's complicated."  But you should understand that there is no limit to the number of adverbs used to modify a verb.  Thus, the idea that something is "the adverb" in a sentence does not make sense. Both "please" and "there" can be adverbs, and additional adverbs like "quickly" or "quietly" could be added as well.