# Can "if", "while", "whenever", "when" recurse deeply? How deeply?

Tags: grammar

I would like a generative BNF-style complete description for English grammar. Some of the more subtle stuff leads to awkward questions of grammaticality (a complete answer to this question, and all related questions, is a publication with a complete description of a comprehensible and comprehensive formal grammar which generates exactly the set of grammatical English sentences)

Here are what I believe to be the toplevel rules (hopefully complete), describing the words of type "if", "when", "and", "maybe", in the situations where these apply at the level of complete sentences (it is not necessary to know BNF to answer the question, I'll generate the confusing examples. In the BNF below, vertical lines separate options, brackets enclose optional constructions, CAPS are nonterminals, lowercase stuff in quotes is actual words you speak)

SENTENCE: IF STATEMENT [THEN] SENTENCE 
| SENTENCE IF STATEMENT 
| SENTENCE AND SENTENCE 
| WHEN STATEMENT SENTENCE 
| MAYBE SENTENCE 
| STATEMENT 
| QUESTION 
| COMMAND 
| ""

IF: "if"| "only if"| "if only"| "if and only if"| "if and if only" 
AND: "and"| "or"| "but" | "else" | "otherwise"
THEN: "then" | "only then" | "then and then only" | "then and only then" 
MAYBE: "maybe" | "possibly" | "perhaps" | "yes" | "no" 
WHEN: "when" | "while" | "unless" | "until" | "whenever" | "while and when" | "when and while" | "whenever and while" | "when and whenever" | "when or whenever" | "whenever and whenever" | "unless and until" | "until and unless" | "whenever and wherever" | "if and when" | "when and if" | "if and while" | "if and whenever" | "whenever and if"

The distinction between the WHEN and IF class is that IF can take THEN, but WHEN cannot. I will ignore commas for the BNF, place them as required from the generative structure. Also, there is a bit of post-processing required here: the sentence can't end up empty.

Anyway, this BNF (assuming you know how to form STATEMENTs, QUESTIONs, and COMMANDs) tells you exactly how to use the IF THEN AND WHEN word at the top level of grammar.

I should point out that there will be a redundancy in the description, in that the words in the MAYBE class are adverbs, and will occur inside statements, questions, and so on as adverbs too.

#### Counterintuitive productions

Nested "if"s start to sound weird, although they are fine by the BNF rules:

- If if John writes Jane reads james falls.

Is this production considered grammatical?

- If jane reads if john writes then james falls.

This one sounds ok, but it is just a reordering of the previous one

- If, if, if john runs to the store Jane runs to the bank, James eats, linda falls

Is this one ok? Stuffing in the "then"s

- If, if, if John runs to the store then jane runs to the bank, then James eats, then Linda falls.

Rearranging using different options for expanding if-then,

- If, James eats if Jane runs to the bank, if John runs to the store, then Linda cries.

This sounds ok to my ears. Is it ok?

There are also counterintuitive productions:

- yes yes maybe possibly no, I will go to the store.

Is this grammatical?

#### EDIT: In response to comments and downvote

I was using unnaturally short statements inside the if's, because the exact nature of the sentences inside is irrelevant. But it seems to psychologically make a difference. Here are more natural sounding versions, with different tenses and more semantic meaningfulness:

- Me: If, only if John helps her will Jane cook, I'm not going to eat. I hate John's cooking.

Is this production considered grammatical?

- Me: If jane cooks only if john helps her then I'm not going to eat. I hate John's cooking

This one sounds ok, but it is just a reordering of the previous one

- Jane: If, if, only if John helps me will I cook you won't eat then I won't ever invite you to my house again!

Is this one ok? Stuffing in the "then"s

- Jane: If, if, only if John helps me will I cook then you won't eat, then I won't ever invite you to my house again!

Rearranging using different options for expanding if-then,

- Jane: If, you wont eat if I will cook only if John helps me, then I won't ever invite you to my house again!

This sounds ok to my ears. Is it ok? It's just a transformational rearrangement of the previous Jane utterances.

There are also counterintuitive productions:

- Me: yes yes maybe possibly no, I don't know whether I will stay for dinner.

Is this grammatical?

Comment: I don't even… But, I mean, ahh!

Comment: When you say "English", do you mean "the language spoken by people who speak English"?  Or are you constructing something completely different?

Comment: @David Wallace: I am sorry--- all the normal stuff people say is produced by the BNF, but it also produces weird stuff that nobody ever says. I just wanted other people's opinions about whether that stuff is grammatical or not. If people say it isn't grammatical, I can add rules to get rid of it.

Comment: My point was, no native speaker would ever say these things.  To a descriptivist, this is more-or-less a definition of ungrammatical; a prescriptivist's mileage may vary.

Comment: @David Wallace: The thing is, some of the simpler utterances in this class are everyday statements like "if sally cooks only if john writes then I'll go to a restaurant."

Comment: You ARE aware that by trying to reduce a natural-language to a BNF form, you are, in effect, ignoring the better part of a century's worth of linguistic research, right?

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: I am not ignoring it exactly, I am reviving a dormant line that I think was stupidly abandoned because the linguists don't know how to program.

Comment: So you're taking a man-made, artificially-constrained concept of a formally-defined language, and attempting to apply its basic premise on something else entirely? Why would English, or any other natural language, fit into the BNF schema? It's like trying to fit, let's say, percipitation patterns into the BNF. It might seem to make sense for an isolated subset, but it's using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: BNF describes English recursion to a tee, and English is the perfect language for a BNF description (most natural languages are, with a few exceptions). This is Chomsky's forgotten insight--- that natural language is basically context free, with only a little bit of context left over. This is obvious to anyone who uses BNF, and draws natural language parse-trees. I wrote a BNF sketch for English several years ago that I know hits the bullseye, it describes the grammar precisely. But there are details that I want to get ironed out, so I am asking other speakers.

Comment: @Kris, you are right to doubt the term *English* grammer; all the Grammers listed in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammer) (Billy, Tracy, Red, Elijah, Kelsey, Spencer, Indiana) are American.

Comment: @RonMaimon You think you are smarter than all those “stupid” linguists who “don’t know how to program”. I disagree. I think that, collectively, they were smarter than you. I think they were smart enough to figure out that the “details” that need to be “ironed out” were, in fact, the *reductio ad absurdum* that showed the whole project was flawed. You are asking us to help you fix the unfixable.

Comment: I think a basic problem with your search for a formal description of English grammar is the belief that such a beast even exists. What is grammatical in New Jersey might be off in Edinburgh. What's right in Johannesburg is unreadable in Auckland.
And that's just when considering geography. How about time? We can understand Shakespeare, Byron or Dickens, but many of their texts would be considered ungrammatical today.

Comment: Formal languages can be formally defined because there's a committee that defines C++0x and its changes from C++98. There's no such thing for English. Even languages with a stronger regulatory body, such as Hebrew or French, have regional and historical variation. How do you intend to capture that, not to mention FUTURE variations?

Comment: You keep using the word "grammatical" in a sense in which it simply doesn't apply.

Comment: To reiterate what I wrote in comments to my own answer: When you are considering what can and cannot be parsed, it is a mistake to consider “If A B.” and “A if B.” as being equivalent.  If you dig inside the neural hardware, you will find that there is a pattern matcher for each of these forms.  That is why “If A B if C.” is comprehensible, but “If if A B C.” is not.

Comment: @Pitarou: I am not asking you for help with the BNF, I already have it! It works fine. It just produces some sentences that came as a surprise to me, and I am asking how they sound to other fluent speakers. The linguists _would_ be collectively smarter, if their field was not sick. They are not, because of their allergy to mathematics. Proof is, they don't have a BNF for English and I do.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: The grammar of English is set in stone. It hasn't changed in any major way since Shakespeare's time. A few words drift in and out of certain classes, a word adds to a class or goes out of one, a required argument is dropped from a verb. These are trivial modifications, and I can write down 16th century BNFs, 18th century BNFs etc. It's not very hard to produce English. What is hard is to _parse_ English, because of the ambiguities in going backwards, like in "I ate the chicken with a fork", is it the Chicken that has the fork? It is also hard to make a standard BNF.

Comment: But if you reduce "grammar" to the things that follow a standardized schema, you will be excluding from it the MAJORITY of actual communication done in that language. Actual language usage is, for the most part, non-grammatical. It's pragmatic, dependent on context and location. Sentences that bear no resemblance to formal grammar are parsed easily by native speakers, while perfectly grammatical sentences can stump the most avid reader. Any scheme you manage to construct might be comprehensive for a certain "English grammar", but probably useless.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: You think I didn't sit down with several newspapers to check that I had everything? Indeed, there are sentences that don't follow the formal grammar, but they don't appear in the New York Times.

Comment: @RobMainon Of course English has these structures, and of course you can use a BNF-style language to describe them. Nobody denies that. The problem is that pure BNF is far too inclusive. It allows sentences that are ungrammatical, or sentences like “If if A B C.” that are so unparseable that any native speaker would dismiss them as ungrammatical, which is the same thing. You’re not going to get away from this problem until you use tools that match the way the human brain works, rather than the way `lex` and `yacc` work.

Comment: @RobMainon You will notice that some people criticise your approach as too exclusive, and some people criticise your approach as too inclusive. You might be tempted to conclude that this is a sign that you’re getting something right. Don’t kid yourself. It’s a sign that the model you are using is a poor fit for the system it attempts to describe. If you really think you have something, use your model to derive results that are both **surprising** and **confirmed by reality**. Until then, your model is just low-hanging fruit for Occam's Razor.

Comment: @Pitarou: You are wrong, and "lex" and "yacc" are obviously the correct tools (if you add a new ingredient). It is dead easy to exclude "if if if X Y Z T" in the formal grammar, keeping "If Z, if, Y if X then T". I don't _want to_ exclude it, because after looking at the examples and the grammar, they sound ok to me now. I was thinking they might sound ok to other speakers to. This was a surprising prediction, confirmed by my intuition. Is it confirmed by other speaker's intuitions? I don't think the people commenting have given it enough thought--- it took me a while to accept "if if X Y Z"

Comment: @Pitarou: The good BNFs includes no sentence that I find ungrammatical--- all the parsable sentences are correct, period. It is just a formal description of the honest-to-goodness grammar. But it is too inclusive only in the sense that some of the sentences require you to rack your brain, so they are bad style. I wasn't asking for a "good style" BNF, but for a "grammatical" BNF. By the way, BNF is not enough--- I found that it is essential to introduce a commutativity property at each level of recursion, to reduce fake ambiguity, and this idea might be new.

Comment: @RonMaimon Your model does not predict, or explain why, “If A if B C.” and “If when A B C.” are acceptable but “If if A B C.” is not. You just have to add it as an arbitrary rule. The neural pattern matching model I alluded to earlier **predicts** this result. It also explains why we cope well with ambiguity but are baffled by garden path sentences, which is the opposite of what we’d expect from `lex`. Oh ... and it is supported by neurological evidence, too. You’re going to have to do a hell of a lot better than that to convince me that you have found something the linguists missed.

Comment: @RonMaimon I shan’t say any more on the matter. (Unless, of course, you come up with something really convincing, in which case I’ll come back to eat humble pie and bow before your awesome, iconoclastic intellect.)

Comment: @Pitarou: I am not discounting your idea--- it is probably true that the scan is more difficult because of the pattern-matching difficulties and stack-pushing difficulties. It is just not the question I am interested in. I want a complete description of New York Times English, one which is minimal and correct. This is given by a modified BNF. Some of the constructions have scanning difficulties, but they are _acceptable_ to my ear. "If if A B C" is fine to my ear. I see that it does not seem fine to you, but that is not a consensus. I never claimed any awesome intellect, this BNF stuff is old.

Comment: Seems that the examples you give above show that your BNF has very little relation to what is actually considered good, comprehensible, grammatically correct English. You seem to be saying, "My BNF works, there's just the small detail that it produces lots of sentences that aren't valid English and fails to produce lots of sentences that are", well, hmm, isn't that the definition of "doesn't work"? I strongly suspect that trying to write a BNF for English is hopeless. As others have said, it's just the wrong tool for the job. Natural language is just not that structured. Maybe it' ...

Comment: ... possible to construct something that would work, but it would have to be hugely complex. Computer languages are trivially simple compared to common English speech. I don't know why you're trying to do this. Say you succeeded, and wrote this BNF that's 10,000 pages long or whatever it would take. What would you do with it? What's the point?

Comment: @Jay: "Good", "comprehensible" and "grammatically correct" are three completely distinct things, they are mixed up by your intuition as related. They are not related and I am not looking to describe either of the first two. The BNF works for "grammatically correct", it produces sentences which, with effort, are seen to be grammatically correct. it doesn't work for "good" or "comprehensible", which are human things that require understanding the sentence. The structure of English grammar is relatively simple, it is not at all related to semantics, and it can be described by a simple algorithm.

Comment: Old thread, and I see only people criticizing @Ron, that's the wrong approach, that he is missing the point, but I could find only non-falsifiable//begging the question arguments (wrong tool/your project will be too long, you'll never achieve something useful). What's exactly the problem of describing EN with BNF? Does anybody have any proof that EN can't be described with BNF? Or at least a proof that there is no such application for it?  Why can't he keep on constructively adding and removing expressions as more things turn out to be un/grammatical? What's better approach he should take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backus-Naur Form is useful for describing the kinds of grammars that are easy for stack machines to parse.  Your brain is not a stack machine.

In your brain, the patterns for structures like “if” and “when” are etched into your neurons as pattern matchers.  They sample the speech coming in, and activate whenever they recognise certain patterns.

You have **one** *if*-pattern recogniser in your brain.  Just one.  You have **one** *when*-pattern recogniser in your brain.  Just one.  If you try to nest *if*-patterns, you are using the same piece of hardware to match two different sentences at the same time.  That doesn’t work, so the sentence becomes unreadable.  However, you can nest **different** kinds of sentence pattern without too much trouble.

So these are just about comprehensible:

> If when John writes Jane reads James fails.
>
> When if John writes Jane reads James fails.

But these are not:

> If if John writes Jane reads James fails.
>
> When when John writes Jane reads James fails.

So go ahead and write a BNF description of English grammar if you want — I’m sure it’s an interesting and instructive exercies — but if you really want an accurate description of English you’re using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: This is a restriction I was toying with--- only allowing one if. But then the sentence "If Jane will cook only if her husband learns spanish then I'm going home." with two ifs. Or "If Jane will cook only if her husband watches TV if the TV is working, then I'm going home." with 3 ifs. I just used short STATEMENTs because I wanted to get at the pattern. I am not sure how many ifs is too many. The BNF describes natural English by the way, not turing-ese. It works for those languages a stack-machine can parse, and it our language brain, for some mysterious reason, is a stack machine.

Comment: If David can explain if Ron's sentences are grammatical, reputation will ensue?

Comment: I’ll amend my answer to say “stack machine” rather than “Turing machine”.

Brains are **not** stack machines.  If they were, people could hold far more than 7±2 digits in their short term memory.  That is why BNF is not appropriate.

Clauses can be nested, but only when the nesting is at the **end** of the clause.  This is because ... well ... in the language of BNF and stack machines you can parse this without deepening the stack.  It’s really a kind of tail call.

If you want to know more about this, ask me, and I’ll amend my answer to explain it more fully.

Comment: "If David can explain if Ron's sentences are grammatical, will reputation ensue?" Absolutely! But it's more of a feeling, and I'm not sure if I am asking the right way. Perhaps I should have made more effort to make the sentences sound natural.

Comment: @Pitarou: I already know all that. The point is that although we only can parse center-embeddings a few levels deep naturally, we can, by thinking, recognize deeper embeddings as grammatical (although hard to understand). The abstract structure we have in our heads is a BNF, although in real life we restrict the center-embedding complexity. I don't care about that--- the examples I give are weird with only one or two levels of embedding, not because we've exhausted the stack.

Comment: Your “If ... only if ....” example is not really relevant.  Although the two patterns (“If A then B” and “A only if B”) use the same keyword, they are **not** the same structure, and they are handled by different pattern matchers.  On the whole, your brain handles this kind of ambiguity much better than a BNF parser can, but it has other limitations.  To get a better understanding, try reading about garden path sentences.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence  Or just read *The Language Instinct* by Steven Pinker.

Comment: If we show a sentence like “If if A B C” to a native speaker with no grammatical training, his first reaction would be to dismiss it as nonsense.  Sure, you could sit down with the speaker and show him how to pick apart the sentence and make sense of it, but then what you’re really doing is bringing into play other parts of the brain that are not normally involved with speech processing.  An interesting exercise, but not really relevant to understanding English as it is used.

Comment: @Pitarou: I only used "only if" to jar your pattern matcher. You can add a restriction that IF's are not allowed to nest with the same IF phrase: but then "If the congress of the United states convenes if it's night, then we have a nighttime congress." becomes ungrammatical. Also "If the congress of the united states convenes if it's warm if not windy, I'm happy.", where I used a shortening trick to make the structure sound better. I believe that "if if A B C" will just make a native speaker pause and think, and say "I don't know if its grammatical, maybe". This is what happened to me.

Comment: @Pitarou: I think I know why double-if is disfavored--- doubled words are easily produced by speakers who pause to think. Like "if... if you can wire computers if they're PCs, Do it!" So you tend to avoid ifs next to each other in grammatical constructions, that's all. They are still formally grammatical, just disfavored.

Comment: @Pitarou: I accepted your answer, and I think you have a point about the pattern matching--- I will keep it in mind. Thanks for your input, and sorry for being overly-argumentative.

Answer (score 5):

I find the following grammatical, but only just.

> Please advise if anyone can judge if David can explain if Ron's
>   sentences are grammatical if they meet his BNF specification.

However, I strongly agree with Avner's comment that BNF is really the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: +1: thanks, I am not sure that the "if" in the embedded part is not a different kind of "if", a substitute for "whether". Maybe this isn't the exact same "if" I was using. Does this mean you consider all the sentences I gave un-grammatical? BNF is not the wrong tool, by the way, it is the right tool, but it needs to be augmented with commutativity and variables to avoid making 1,000 different kinds of nodes (which is typical of natural language processing using BNFs).

Answer (score 3):

In general, humans appear to have trouble interpreting sentences where you would need to mentally 'keep a lot on the stack' in order to parse the sentence. So for example, the following is in principle grammatical but in practice difficult to interpret:

> The plane the aide the president chose flew in landed.

On the other hand, the following involves a similar level of recursion in principle, but in practice you only need to unwind the stack 'one level at a time' (or arguably don't actually need a stack at all) to interpret it:

> My girlfriend's mother's dog died.
>
> This is the dog that chased the cat that chased the mouse.

I think this difference is usually referred to as 'nested recursion' vs 'tail recursion'. We can handle several levels of tail recursion quite readily, but usually only very shallow nested recursion.

If you're interested in this topic further, you may like to look at e.g. van der Hulst (ed), "Recursion and human language" -- and indeed see what different books on (human language) syntax have to say about recursion.

Comment: I know all this, it's true. The examples I use do not center recurse very far, and should be handled easily. This is not the problem with them. The problem with them is the repeating "if".